# I want the know that (formula) how to calculate the RAM, CPU & disk memory of namenode, yarn & Resource Manager

Tags: hadoop, mapreduce, hadoop-yarn, resourcemanager, namenode

I am trying to build the cluster on different sizes, and that is why I want the formulas from which I can calculate the RAM, CPU & disk memory of namenode, yarn & Resource Manager.
also want to know that how RAM, CPU & Disk related to each other.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use Cloudera Guide [Download](https://www.google.co.in/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=4&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=0ahUKEwjJtcHgz4bOAhXLo48KHacaCOQQFggpMAM&url=http%3A%2F%2Ftiny.cloudera.com%2Fyarn-tuning-guide&usg=AFQjCNGiDLhSH2Xlv4OWaum8k_XQ9oeihw&sig2=331KFdKAQL5STRyZgCEFSw&bvm=bv.127521224,d.c2I)